# Error running fabcar javascript chaincode in Hyperledger fabric 1.4.3

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I changed the ./startFabric.sh file to use javascript as the chaincode language (CC_SRC_LANGUAGE=${1:-"javascript"}. I get the following while trying to instantiate the javascript chaincode.

```
Instantiating smart contract on mychannel
+ docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -l node -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P 'AND('\''Org1MSP.member'\'','\''Org2MSP.member'\'')' --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
2019-09-23 21:35:15.103 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2019-09-23 21:35:15.103 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 127
```

I am using MacOS 10.14.6 and Docker version 2.1.0.3 Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: That single change to the script should not cause the failure.  Did the 'install' commands complete without error?  Have you checked the Peer logs for errors?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it was driving me crazy. 
So I did analysis and fixed it.

Here is what I did. 
*** not sure if all of these matter until I perform further analysis, 
but adding the following worked *** :)

1) In startFabric.sh I set CC_SRC_LANGUAGE to javascript:

```
CC_SRC_LANGUAGE=${1:-"javascript"}
```

2) To:

fabric-samples-release-1.4/chaincode/fabcar/javascript/lib/fabcar.js

I added:

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
constructor() {
      super();
  }

  async instantiate(ctx) {
      // No implementation required with this example
      // It could be where data migration is performed, if necessary
      console.log('Instantiate the contract');
  }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

3) In fabric-samples-release-1.4/first-network/byfn.sh I set (this one probably does not matter but not sure until I reset it back to "golang":

```
LANGUAGE="javascript"
```

4) In fabric-samples-release-1.4/chaincode/fabcar/javascript I executed this command:

```
npm install
```

4a) and fixed the errors by executing:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

5) I removed all the existing dev-* images by executing:

docker images -a | grep "dev" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi -f

Then I ran ./startFabric.sh and BINGO! It worked! 
I then cd'd to javascript and was able to execute:

```
node enrollAdmin.js
```

Result: 
Wallet path: /Volumes/WDCWD10JPLX/markmorris/work/work-GO/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples-release-1.4/fabcar/javascript/wallet
Successfully enrolled admin user "admin" and imported it into the wallet

```
node registerUser.js
```

Result:
Wallet path: /Volumes/WDCWD10JPLX/markmorris/work/work-GO/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples-release-1.4/fabcar/javascript/wallet
Successfully registered and enrolled admin user "user1" and imported it into the wallet

```
node invoke.js
```

Result:
Wallet path: /Volumes/WDCWD10JPLX/markmorris/work/work-GO/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples-release-1.4/fabcar/javascript/wallet
Transaction has been submitted

```
node query.js
```

Result:

```
Wallet path: /Volumes/WDCWD10JPLX/markmorris/work/work-GO/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples-release-1.4/fabcar/javascript/wallet
Transaction has been evaluated, result is: [{"Key":"CAR0","Record":{"color":"blue","docType":"car","make":"Toyota","model":"Prius","owner":"Tomoko"}},{"Key":"CAR1","Record":{"color":"red","docType":"car","make":"Ford","model":"Mustang","owner":"Brad"}},{"Key":"CAR12","Record":{"color":"Black","docType":"car","make":"Honda","model":"Accord","owner":"Tom"}},{"Key":"CAR2","Record":{"color":"green","docType":"car","make":"Hyundai","model":"Tucson","owner":"Jin Soo"}},{"Key":"CAR3","Record":{"color":"yellow","docType":"car","make":"Volkswagen","model":"Passat","owner":"Max"}},{"Key":"CAR4","Record":{"color":"black","docType":"car","make":"Tesla","model":"S","owner":"Adriana"}},{"Key":"CAR5","Record":{"color":"purple","docType":"car","make":"Peugeot","model":"205","owner":"Michel"}},{"Key":"CAR6","Record":{"color":"white","docType":"car","make":"Chery","model":"S22L","owner":"Aarav"}},{"Key":"CAR7","Record":{"color":"violet","docType":"car","make":"Fiat","model":"Punto","owner":"Pari"}},{"Key":"CAR8","Record":{"color":"indigo","docType":"car","make":"Tata","model":"Nano","owner":"Valeria"}},{"Key":"CAR9","Record":{"color":"brown","docType":"car","make":"Holden","model":"Barina","owner":"Shotaro"}}]
```

HERE IS THE OUTPUT I WAS GETTING PRIOR TO MAKING THE ABOVE CHANGES:

```
2019-09-25 06:51:21.186 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2019-09-25 06:51:21.186 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: API error (400): OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/root/chaincode-java/start\": stat /root/chaincode-java/start: no such file or directory": unknown
```

HERE IS THE OUTPUT I GOT AFTER MAKING THE ABOVE CHANGES (NOTE I ENABLED DEBUG SO THAT IS WHY IT IS SO VERBOSE BUT AFTER THE FIRST TWO LINES IS WHERE IT CONTINUES SUCCESSFULLY :)

```
2019-09-25 07:51:26.857 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 04a Using default escc
2019-09-25 07:51:26.858 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 04b Using default vscc
2019-09-25 07:51:26.860 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 04c Sign: plaintext: 0ABF070A6708031A0C08FEB8ACEC0510...324D53500A04657363630A0476736363 
2019-09-25 07:51:26.861 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 04d Sign: digest: 0A1BC3ADA9356F58B11EAF00E809EDF2EF6549EDAD8A4A1BC3830EB3E71751B5 
2019-09-25 07:52:39.247 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 04e Sign: plaintext: 0ABF070A6708031A0C08FEB8ACEC0510...67A03ABE259A7BB2EE5CC8EEFA65822D 
2019-09-25 07:52:39.248 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 04f Sign: digest: 9DEDC23FE7F0917AE54C018FA04650A225877BBE6F5ECD6B254A2EC15678914D 
+ echo 'Waiting for instantiation request to be committed ...'
Waiting for instantiation request to be committed ...
+ sleep 10
+ echo 'Submitting initLedger transaction to smart contract on mychannel'
Submitting initLedger transaction to smart contract on mychannel
+ echo 'The transaction is sent to the two peers with the chaincode installed (peer0.org1.example.com and peer0.org2.example.com) so that chaincode is built before receiving the following requests'
The transaction is sent to the two peers with the chaincode installed (peer0.org1.example.com and peer0.org2.example.com) so that chaincode is built before receiving the following requests
+ docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp cli peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -c '{"function":"initLedger","Args":[]}' --waitForEvent --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
2019-09-25 07:52:49.773 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 001 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP
2019-09-25 07:52:49.773 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 002 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2019-09-25 07:52:49.773 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 003 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.Default setting to string SW
2019-09-25 07:52:49.774 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 004 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW
2019-09-25 07:52:49.774 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 005 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2019-09-25 07:52:49.774 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 006 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Hash setting to string SHA2
2019-09-25 07:52:49.775 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 007 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: 256
2019-09-25 07:52:49.775 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 008 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Security setting to int 256
2019-09-25 07:52:49.775 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 009 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore
2019-09-25 07:52:49.776 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00a Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: unexpected end of JSON input
2019-09-25 07:52:49.776 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00b Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to string 
2019-09-25 07:52:49.776 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00c Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11
2019-09-25 07:52:49.777 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00d Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-09-25 07:52:49.777 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00e Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Library setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-09-25 07:52:49.777 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00f Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-09-25 07:52:49.778 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 010 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Label setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-09-25 07:52:49.778 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 011 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-09-25 07:52:49.779 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 012 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Pin setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-09-25 07:52:49.779 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 013 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-09-25 07:52:49.780 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 014 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Hash setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-09-25 07:52:49.780 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 015 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-09-25 07:52:49.780 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 016 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Security setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-09-25 07:52:49.781 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 017 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore
2019-09-25 07:52:49.781 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 018 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-09-25 07:52:49.782 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 019 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-09-25 07:52:49.782 UTC [viperutil] EnhancedExactUnmarshalKey -> DEBU 01a map[peer.BCCSP:map[Default:SW SW:map[Hash:SHA2 Security:256 FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:]] PKCS11:map[Security:<nil> FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:<nil>] Library:<nil> Label:<nil> Pin:<nil> Hash:<nil>]]]
2019-09-25 07:52:49.784 UTC [bccsp_sw] openKeyStore -> DEBU 01b KeyStore opened at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore]...done
2019-09-25 07:52:49.784 UTC [bccsp] initBCCSP -> DEBU 01c Initialize BCCSP [SW]
2019-09-25 07:52:49.785 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01d Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts
2019-09-25 07:52:49.789 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01e Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
2019-09-25 07:52:49.791 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01f Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts
2019-09-25 07:52:49.794 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 020 Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
2019-09-25 07:52:49.796 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 021 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/admincerts
2019-09-25 07:52:49.799 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 022 Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/admincerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
2019-09-25 07:52:49.802 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 023 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/intermediatecerts
2019-09-25 07:52:49.803 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 024 Intermediate certs folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/intermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/intermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2019-09-25 07:52:49.803 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 025 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts
2019-09-25 07:52:49.809 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 026 Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
2019-09-25 07:52:49.812 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 027 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts
2019-09-25 07:52:49.813 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 028 TLS intermediate certs folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2019-09-25 07:52:49.813 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 029 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/crls
2019-09-25 07:52:49.814 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 02a crls folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/crls]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/crls: no such file or directory]
2019-09-25 07:52:49.815 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 02b MSP configuration file not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/config.yaml]: [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/config.yaml: no such file or directory]
2019-09-25 07:52:49.815 UTC [msp] newBccspMsp -> DEBU 02c Creating BCCSP-based MSP instance
2019-09-25 07:52:49.816 UTC [msp] New -> DEBU 02d Creating Cache-MSP instance
2019-09-25 07:52:49.816 UTC [msp] loadLocaMSP -> DEBU 02e Created new local MSP
2019-09-25 07:52:49.817 UTC [msp] Setup -> DEBU 02f Setting up MSP instance Org1MSP
2019-09-25 07:52:49.818 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 030 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-09-25 07:52:49.818 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 031 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-09-25 07:52:49.821 UTC [bccsp_sw] loadPrivateKey -> DEBU 032 Loading private key [111c761634ff23746d82f6660b3051ddc4635c24b0a3b1cdce55a4a389322fa3] at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/111c761634ff23746d82f6660b3051ddc4635c24b0a3b1cdce55a4a389322fa3_sk]...
2019-09-25 07:52:49.824 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 033 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-09-25 07:52:49.824 UTC [msp] setupSigningIdentity -> DEBU 034 Signing identity expires at 2029-09-22 07:45:00 +0000 UTC
2019-09-25 07:52:49.825 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 035 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-09-25 07:52:49.825 UTC [msp] Validate -> DEBU 036 MSP Org1MSP validating identity
2019-09-25 07:52:49.829 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 037 parsed scheme: ""
2019-09-25 07:52:49.829 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 038 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-09-25 07:52:49.830 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 039 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0.org1.example.com:7051 0  <nil>}]
2019-09-25 07:52:49.831 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03a ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-09-25 07:52:49.831 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03b pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000257fd0, CONNECTING
2019-09-25 07:52:49.836 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000257fd0, READY
2019-09-25 07:52:49.839 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03d parsed scheme: ""
2019-09-25 07:52:49.840 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03e scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-09-25 07:52:49.840 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03f ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0.org1.example.com:7051 0  <nil>}]
2019-09-25 07:52:49.841 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 040 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-09-25 07:52:49.841 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 041 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000546370, CONNECTING
2019-09-25 07:52:49.846 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 042 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000546370, READY
2019-09-25 07:52:49.852 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 043 parsed scheme: ""
2019-09-25 07:52:49.853 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 044 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-09-25 07:52:49.853 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 045 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0.org2.example.com:9051 0  <nil>}]
2019-09-25 07:52:49.854 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 046 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-09-25 07:52:49.854 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 047 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00052e610, CONNECTING
2019-09-25 07:52:49.859 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 048 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00052e610, READY
2019-09-25 07:52:49.863 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 049 parsed scheme: ""
2019-09-25 07:52:49.864 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 04a scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-09-25 07:52:49.865 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 04b ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0.org2.example.com:9051 0  <nil>}]
2019-09-25 07:52:49.866 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 04c ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-09-25 07:52:49.866 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 04d pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0004b28b0, CONNECTING
2019-09-25 07:52:49.871 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 04e pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0004b28b0, READY
2019-09-25 07:52:49.876 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 04f Obtaining default signing identity
2019-09-25 07:52:49.880 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 050 parsed scheme: ""
2019-09-25 07:52:49.881 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 051 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-09-25 07:52:49.881 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 052 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{orderer.example.com:7050 0  <nil>}]
2019-09-25 07:52:49.881 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 053 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-09-25 07:52:49.882 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 054 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0002c3b30, CONNECTING
2019-09-25 07:52:49.886 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 055 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0002c3b30, READY
2019-09-25 07:52:49.886 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 056 Sign: plaintext: 0AC1070A6908031A0C08D1B9ACEC0510...61721A0C0A0A696E69744C6564676572 
2019-09-25 07:52:49.887 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 057 Sign: digest: 22D01CC4ABD5A39F16F3F242B3DE847755511AFECC4E265B85821F55C18E712C 
2019-09-25 07:53:39.973 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 058 Sign: plaintext: 0AC1070A6908031A0C08D1B9ACEC0510...0008C46BAF292692653F6DCF19E193FB 
2019-09-25 07:53:39.974 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 059 Sign: digest: EA323510ACB8506AB87F57B974A6C286CA43EEF3BEE0347A8BA3EAC220C6199A 
2019-09-25 07:53:39.975 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 05a Obtaining default signing identity
2019-09-25 07:53:39.975 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 05b Obtaining default signing identity
2019-09-25 07:53:39.976 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 05c Sign: plaintext: 0AED060A1508051A060883BAACEC0522...00120D1A0B08FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF01 
2019-09-25 07:53:39.977 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 05e Sign: digest: 1AAE1FB1BACA69A6D01C7038432D1DCE7834B25531DC21BED65ECFCC7C80CD51 
2019-09-25 07:53:39.976 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 05d Obtaining default signing identity
2019-09-25 07:53:39.978 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 05f Obtaining default signing identity
2019-09-25 07:53:39.985 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 060 Sign: plaintext: 0AED060A1508051A060883BAACEC0522...00120D1A0B08FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF01 
2019-09-25 07:53:39.988 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 061 Sign: digest: 66037BD6618A22F43AFD131CE9FF21439E948FC7EC6A5FA7F4687088947455B6 
2019-09-25 07:53:43.156 UTC [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> INFO 062 txid [ddc2bbf69ade8c61e71ae603cd05f92a1ccf25725296c095abb7b98b60e80b5c] committed with status (VALID) at peer0.org2.example.com:9051
2019-09-25 07:53:43.166 UTC [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> INFO 063 txid [ddc2bbf69ade8c61e71ae603cd05f92a1ccf25725296c095abb7b98b60e80b5c] committed with status (VALID) at peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2019-09-25 07:53:43.167 UTC [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> DEBU 064 ESCC invoke result: version:1 response:<status:200 > payload:"\n \245\330\026\014\363\341\304\217]\243)\244\352\314g\276\347\264\276\204\035\234\240\250\373\035\261v>\201,j\022\315\007\n\266\007\022\233\007\n\006fabcar\022\220\007\032Y\n\004CAR0\032Q{\"color\":\"blue\",\"make\":\"Toyota\",\"model\":\"Prius\",\"owner\":\"Tomoko\",\"docType\":\"car\"}\032V\n\004CAR1\032N{\"color\":\"red\",\"make\":\"Ford\",\"model\":\"Mustang\",\"owner\":\"Brad\",\"docType\":\"car\"}\032]\n\004CAR2\032U{\"color\":\"green\",\"make\":\"Hyundai\",\"model\":\"Tucson\",\"owner\":\"Jin Soo\",\"docType\":\"car\"}\032]\n\004CAR3\032U{\"color\":\"yellow\",\"make\":\"Volkswagen\",\"model\":\"Passat\",\"owner\":\"Max\",\"docType\":\"car\"}\032V\n\004CAR4\032N{\"color\":\"black\",\"make\":\"Tesla\",\"model\":\"S\",\"owner\":\"Adriana\",\"docType\":\"car\"}\032Z\n\004CAR5\032R{\"color\":\"purple\",\"make\":\"Peugeot\",\"model\":\"205\",\"owner\":\"Michel\",\"docType\":\"car\"}\032W\n\004CAR6\032O{\"color\":\"white\",\"make\":\"Chery\",\"model\":\"S22L\",\"owner\":\"Aarav\",\"docType\":\"car\"}\032W\n\004CAR7\032O{\"color\":\"violet\",\"make\":\"Fiat\",\"model\":\"Punto\",\"owner\":\"Pari\",\"docType\":\"car\"}\032Y\n\004CAR8\032Q{\"color\":\"indigo\",\"make\":\"Tata\",\"model\":\"Nano\",\"owner\":\"Valeria\",\"docType\":\"car\"}\032\\\n\004CAR9\032T{\"color\":\"brown\",\"make\":\"Holden\",\"model\":\"Barina\",\"owner\":\"Shotaro\",\"docType\":\"car\"}\022\026\n\004lscc\022\016\n\014\n\006fabcar\022\002\010\003\032\003\010\310\001\"\r\022\006fabcar\032\0031.0" endorsement:<endorser:"\n\007Org1MSP\022\252\006-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nKlX4tNyER/D+W2z5efiZdasjghsewzgEqYyyTQ==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" signature:"0E\002!\000\254\\\321KW]=\267-\t\336\226U\334\344Z\324\203\005)\251:!h\226\332@\277]&t\204\002 \036\235\227\366z\221\230\033i\030'r\252\\,\350\005\240>w\315\252\363\376@\214\225\263\341,\362\355" > 
2019-09-25 07:53:43.167 UTC [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> INFO 065 Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200 
+ set +x

Total setup execution time : 207 secs ...
```

Comment: Your suggestions worked really well. Thanks a million.

Comment: Thanks! Happy you liked my answer and it worked for you. Please upvote my answer.

Comment: I am trying to run the typescript version by changing ./startFabric.sh file to use typescript as the chaincode language (CC_SRC_LANGUAGE=${1:-"typescript"} and I get "Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1" while trying to instantiate the chaincode. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use all caps.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the 
`Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: API error (400): OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/root/chaincode-java/start\": stat /root/chaincode-java/start: no such file or directory": unknown`

And I find that is because I didn't completely cleaned up the environment.